# Show/Hide not working

Tags: jquery, silverstripe

I'm not sure if this is a SilverStripe or a JavaScript issue because I am new to JS but here goes.

I am trying something that should be simple but having trouble.  I want to show/hide a field based on a dropdown.  It is 50% working as the field is hidden/shown when toggled but only if rejected is selected when the document loads.  Can anyone spot my mistake so I don't spend weeks on this? I've used firebug and found that the field never gets added if it's pending or accepted.

```
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropDown = $('#DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Status');
    var reason = $('#Reason');

    if(dropDown.val() == 'rejected' || dropDown.val() == 'Rejected'){
        reason.show();
    }

    dropDown.change(function (e) {
        if(dropDown.val() == 'rejected'){   
            reason.show();
        }
        else{
            reason.hide();
        }
   }).change();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: @MillyMonster I think dropDown.val() is the problem.

Comment: First of all why are you using `ready()` function inside `self invoked function`?

Comment: Try to sanitize the value from the field by applying $.trim() to it before you compare it to a string literal

Comment: It seems working for me. Here is jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/k4FfU/

Comment: Thanks for all the fast replies.  @al0neevenings that answers my first question then.  It's a SilverStripe issue, not a JQuery one. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to your Silverstripe code. I've put together a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/tq2Qy/1/

Let me know if you've any questions